# How to get all Movies with rating between x and y from my Movie class?

Tags: java

I am basically a beginner at Java, been going to a course for around 3 and a half weeks. We've been doing Classes and Objects last few classes, and now, I've gotten this assignment to create Class called Movies and another one AnimatedMovies.

My Movie Class has the following attributes: Name, Actors[], averageRating, Director, Year of Release.

I've successfully completed 9 out of 10 parts of this assignment and got stuck at the last part, that needs to list all the movies between rating that the user enters.

So I've created a Scanner that lets the user input the lowest and highest IMDB rating, and my program should then print all the movies in that range, so if the user enters 6 for lowest and 8 for highest, it should list all movies with a rating between 6 and 8.

I have around 30 movies created (movie1, movie2, etc).

How do I set it up so it goes thru all of them and list name of the movies between the range?

I can only get it to work with one movie with this simple if statement:

```
`if (movie1.getIMDB() > vb &&  movie1.getIMDB() < mb) {
    System.out.println(movie1.nameOfTheMovie);
    } else {
    System.out.println("There are no movies in selected range");
    }`
```

It works for the first movie of course, so how do I go thru all of the 30 (or if I create 1000 of movies) with one got. I am guessing I need to use For loop but don't know how to set it up.

Answer (score 2):

Setup a List with all your movies and iterate over them with a simple for loop.
Some examples:

```
Movie spiderman = new Movie(10,"Spiderman");
List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
movies.add(spiderman);
```

**Normal for loop:**

```
 for(int i = 0; i< movies.size();i++){
        Movie movie = movies.get(i);
        if(movie.averageRating < 10 && movie.averageRating > 5){
            System.out.println(movie.name);
        }
 }
```

**Foreach:**

```
for(Movie movie : movies){
    if(movie.averageRating < 10 && movie.averageRating > 5){
        System.out.println(movie.name);
    }
}
```

**Stream:**

```
movies.stream().filter(movie -> movie.averageRating < 10 && movie.averageRating > 5).forEach(movie -> System.out.println(movie.name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Z3RP, for answering. We didn't go over lists at our class yet, but I managed to solve it on my own. It was as simple as it gets...

I just needed to add: Movie movies [] = {movie1, movie2, movie3, movie4, movie5};

and it works like a charm...

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Bigger than: ");
double vb = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Lower than: ");
double mb = sc.nextInt();


Movie movies [] = {movie1, movie2, movie3, movie4, movie5};


for (int i = 0; i <movies.length; i++) {
    if (movies[i].averageRating > vb &&  movies[i].averageRating < mb) {
        System.out.println( movies[i].nameOfTheMovie+ " , rating is: " + movies[i].averageRating);

    }else {

    }
```

Follow up question, how would I return "There are no movies in selected range" if I put it in else if and select range without any movie it returns that message but 5x (length of a movie string)...